# why BottomSheetBehavior in androidx error The view is not a child of CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I use `androidx` and material Bottom Sheet Modal persistent. but my code is error like this :

`The view is not a child of CoordinatorLayout`

bottom_sheet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="72dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_margin"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Order Details"
            android:textColor="#444"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="₹435.00"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chicken Fried Rice 1x1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Paneer Tikka 1x2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:text="Delivery Address"
        android:textColor="#444"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Flat No 404, Skyline Apartments, Vizag - 500576" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:text="PROCEED PAYMENT"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#efefef"
    tools:context="com.app.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <!-- Adding bottom sheet after main content -->
    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @BindView(R.id.btn_bottom_sheet)
    Button btnBottomSheet;

    @BindView(R.id.bottom_sheet)
    LinearLayout layoutBottomSheet;

    BottomSheetBehavior sheetBehavior;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

//        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        sheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(layoutBottomSheet);

        /**
         * bottom sheet state change listener
         * we are changing button text when sheet changed state
         * */
        sheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                switch (newState) {
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED: {
                        btnBottomSheet.setText("Close Sheet");
                    }
                    break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED: {
                        btnBottomSheet.setText("Expand Sheet");
                    }
                    break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * manually opening / closing bottom sheet on button click
     */
    @OnClick(R.id.btn_bottom_sheet)
    public void toggleBottomSheet() {
        if (sheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            btnBottomSheet.setText("Close sheet");
        } else {
            sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            btnBottomSheet.setText("Expand sheet");
        }
    }
}
```

where I wrong, and how to solve this, I already google about this problem, but I got no clue.

error in `sheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(layoutBottomSheet);`

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parent layout is a `ConstraintLayout` not a `CoordinatorLayout`